# Computing the derivative of a function with ifft

Tags: fft

I would like to generate a 2D texture by first generating some 2D frequency domain coefficients and then using ifft to generate the texture. To compute the normal map I would like to take derivative of this 2D function. I just want to know if the following is correct:

```
in 1D I would just do a loop for (k = 0; k < N, k++) coefficients[k] *= i * k; where i is sqrt(-1)
in 2D I should do this? for (m=0;m<N;m++) for (n=0;n<N;n++) coefficients[m,n] *= (i*m)*(i*n) -> -m*n;
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2D, the "derivative" is the 2D gradient vector whose components are, in spatial domain, partial derivatives w.r.t. coordianate axes (usually denoted x and y). So, you will do `coefficients[m,n] *= i*m` for one axis, and `coefficients[m,n] *= i*n` for the other axis. You will apply inverse 2D fft to each of these two, to get images of partial derivative d/dx and partial derivative d/dy. The normal will then be the vector (d/dx, d/dy, -1) normalized to length 1.

Comment: So you're saying I should create 2 set of coefficients and run 2 separate 1D ifft on them?

Comment: Not really. To each of them, you will apply 2d ifft. This info added to answer.

Comment: do you mean coefficients[m,n] *= i*n?

Comment: I'm taking the real component of the original ifft as the height, since the imaginary component of the original coefficients are all 0. If the coefficient is a+bi where b=0, then after multiplying by i*n I get a complex coefficient 0+a*n*i. Does I use only the real component of the resulting ifft or do I use sqrt(re*re+im*im)?

Comment: `=` corrected to `*=`, thanks. As for the second question, consider this: you are creating a height function in the frequency domain. If you do this right, the IFFT of that will be a real function (I assume that you know how to do this, because this is not the topic of your original question). The IFFT may have small imaginary part due to numerics (in the order of 1e-13 or so). The same is true about derivatives. You are computing derivatives of **real** function in the frequency domain. The IFFT of that will be real, if not, the implementation has a bug.